# NextJs get content of click item on next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, single-page-application, next.js

I have a simple nextjs app, on the homepage I just show a list of 10 movies with a Button / Link, which open the specific page for that movie. On that page I would like to show all the content for that movie.

My first approach was to add the movie id to the Link like this:

```
  <Link href="/movies/[title]" as={`/movies/${movie._id}-${movie.title}`} prefetch>
    <IconButton aria-label="Open">
      <LaunchIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Link>
```

And trim the id from the url from the next page and sent an additional request to the api to get the information for that movie. But I am pretty sure that this is not good practice.

Inside the single movie component / `movies/[title].tsx`.
I tried to create a basic movie object

```
const movieObj = {
  _id: 1,
  title: "",
  release_at: new Date(),
  created_at: new Date()
};
```

and set that data using hooks:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState<IMovie>(movieObj);
```

How can I achieve a good solution with nextjs?

Comment: So, you have 10 elements with 10 buttons "showDetails" on the page (/movies). You like to have onclick trigger that redirects to /movies/[title].tsx where you show your details. It's true?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [nextjs document](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router). As said in the docs, you can reach URL slugs via useRouter hook.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();    
const { title } = router.query;
```